# How to get username in request.GET Django

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial to add friends in Django: [Building Friend Networks](https://www.packtpub.com/article/building-friend-networks-with-django-1.0)

I am getting a 404 page because I have set it in my code to raise a Http404 if the username was not found in request.GET:

views.py:

```
def friend_add(request):
    if 'username' in request.GET:
        friend = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.GET['username'])
        friendship = Friendship(from_friend=request.user, to_friend=friend)
        friendship.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/friends/%s' % request.user.username)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^friend/add/(?P<username>\w+)$', photo.views.friends_request),
url(r'^friends/(?P<username>\w+)$', photo.views.friends),
url(r'^request_sent/$', photo.views.friend_add),
```

I am using template tags like this as shown from the tutorial:

```
{% ifequal user.username abuild.user %}
    <a href="/builds/friends/{{ user.username }}">view your friends</a>
{% else %}
    {% if is_friend %}
        <a href="/builds/friends/{{ abuild.user }}">
        {{ abuild.user }} is a friend of yours</a> 
    {% else %}
        <a href="/builds/request_sent/">
        add {{ abuild.user}} to your friends</a> 
    {% endif %}
    - <a href="/builds/friends/{{ abuild.user }}">
    view {{abuild.user}}'s friends</a>
{% endifequal %}
```

How do I ensure that I am getting the username when I click on a link that goes to `/request_sent/`?

`abuild.user` is the user who I am trying to add, while `user.username` is the person logged in.

Comment: You could add it to a query string in your template, or use a form with a GET action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the username in the url as you are doing in other cases.

So your template would change to

```
<a href="/builds/request_sent/{{abuild.user.username}}">
```

urls.py would change to

```
 url(r'^request_sent/(?P<username>\w+)$', photo.views.friend_add),
```

And then view would change to

```
def friend_add(request, username):
    if 'username' in request.GET:
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! I pulled an all nighter today, so I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: Hey @Rohan, I actually tried this right now, and I still get the 404 error, any idea?